# Global package import in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have different modules in my node.js application where I ended up importing the same package( for example moment npm).

I am wondering If I we have a better way to import all dependencies at one place and use it like a global import so that no individual modules need separate npm modules import import

Comment: Best practice is to avoid polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Modules were designed into the core of node.js for a couple reasons:

1. Create a separate variable namespace for each module so there are no variable naming collisions.
2. Make code reuse and sharing something that is built into the core of node.js (just look at the huge library of things in NPM to see how that worked).
3. Increase independence of each block of functionality to make things more independently testable, ease the creation of unit tests for a whole module, etc...
4. Make dependencies between code obvious and clear (stated rather than implicit).

To achieve these advantages, you do not rely on a global namespace for anything except a few core built-in features.  And, you ask every single module to declaratively import the other modules that it needs.

The cost of this is a little extra boilerplate at the top of each module where it imports all the things that it needs.  These modules are cached so it isn't really much run-time overhead, but is some repeated coding in each module.  So, if you needed access to the moment module in 10 of your modules, then you would import it separately in each of the 10 modules.  While that may seem redundant and something you should get rid of (coming from a non-module world), it's the small cost of getting all the above advantages of modules.

It's really something you just get used to over time in node.js development.  Each module just starts by importing the other modules that it depends upon.  Yes, there's some repeated code, but that's how you get the other advantages of modularity.

As soon as you start stuffing things in the global namespace to prevent a little typing at the start of a module, you start creating implicit (non-declarative) dependencies.  You make your code more difficult to share or reuse in other projects and you open the possibility for variable naming collision (just imagine if the 10 things you use from NPM all did this too or just imagine 10 people working on your project, all doing that).

So, think of it like brushing your teeth.  It's a pain to do every time, but if you don't you pay the piper down the road.  Just import in the external modules you need in every one of your modules.